# Sending data to a webpage that is not mine

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, html, send

Is it possible to have a viewController in an iOS app with some textboxes where the user inputs some strings and then with a button sends it to a webpage which is NOT mine? Here is an example of a webpage (http://www.nattklubbvictoria.se/#/list) with some choices, text boxes and a Send button. The websites is using some sort of widget. If it is possible, how?

Currently I have a uiweview but it's not so good looking and it's slow to load it. So it would be awesome if I could do this!

Comment: How would the app know whether a web page is "yours" or not? The only problems with what you're trying to do are: 1) the owner of the page in question may not appreciate it; and 2) it's pretty much inevitable that the page will change and your app may break.

Comment: Yes I understand, but I am pretty sure the owner will like it after all because I advertise them and the page wants many users to sign up there and visit them, I just make it simpler for the user. So it may only work good if I talk with them and get access to the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as construct a GET URL & forward the user to that URL when the user clicks the button.

For example (not tested):

```
NSString *stringToSendUserTo = @"http://www.site.com/form.php?foreignParameterA=";
stringToSendUserTo = [stringToSendUserTo stringByAppendingString:firstTextField.text];
stringToSendUserTo = [stringToSendUserTo stringByAppendingString:@"&foreignParameterB="];
stringToSendUserTo = [stringToSendUserTo stringByAppendingString:secondTextField.text];

stringToSendUserTo = [stringToSendUserTo stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *URLToSendUserTo = [NSURL URLWithString:stringToSendUserTo];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:URLToSendUserTo]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URLToSendUserTo];
} else {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: But does this only work if it's a PHP site? Cause I'm not sure it is a PHP site.

Comment: This solution is not specific to PHP; I simply used PHP as an example. The solution will work for any web platform that adheres to the GET convention for passing parameters via a URL. Here is a link relating to URI conventions: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/